# Layout class variable not rcognised by android studio IDE

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I am new to android development and hence was following along a [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBWyXo-3JGQ&t=836s) on how to make a basic todolist app. In between the tutorial I seem to be getting stuck, although I followed the video as such.

The IDE says that inside the function 'onBindViewHolder', there are no import candidates for 'tvTodoTitle' (line 29)

Im not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

I am using android-studio hdegehog

## TodoAdapter.kt

```kotlin
package com.example.test

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class TodoAdapter (
    private val todos: MutableList<Todo>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>() {
    class TodoViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder {
        return TodoViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.item_todo,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val curTodo = todos[position]
        holder.itemView.apply {
            tvTodoTitle.text = curTodo.title
        }
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return todos.size
    }
}
```

## Attaching a screenshot of the onscreen error

[image]

this references to a markdown file: item_todo.xml

## item_todo.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTodoTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Example"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cbDone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbDone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried comparing the code with the project [repo](https://github.com/philipplackner/TodoList/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/todolist/MainActivity.kt) attached in the link description. I wasnt able to find an differences as such.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you are trying to access it from the `itemView` instead of `holder`.

here is the corrected code:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val curTodo = todos[position]
    holder.itemView.apply {
        // Change the following line
        // tvTodoTitle.text = curTodo.title
        // to
        holder.tvTodoTitle.text = curTodo.title
    }
}
```

In the `onBindViewHolder` function, `holder` is the instance of `TodoViewHolder` that represents the current item in the RecyclerView. Therefore, you should use `holder`.`tvTodoTitle` to access the `TextView` within that specific item.

Another approach is to use the `holder` directly without accessing `itemView.apply`.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val curTodo = todos[position]

    // Use the holder directly without itemView.apply
    holder.tvTodoTitle.text = curTodo.title
}
```

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: Hi, thanks

this worked, but this works only when i explicitely return variables in the TodoViewHolder class. Is there any way to have the same functionality without `val tvTodoTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTodoTitle)` inside TodoViewHolder class?

Comment: you can use, viewBinding, if you don't want to use `findViewById`.  if you enable viewBinding in your project then you can access any view direct with it's id, for your item_todo, it'll be `itemTodoBinding.tvTodoTitle`.

if the answer works, please mark this answer as "Accepted", thanks!

Comment: there's no point in doing `apply` if you're just going to do `holder.tvTodoTitle.text = curTodo.title` in the next line